# How can estimate cox model with lifelines package?

Tags: python

I want to estimate cox models but when I try to run the code ,I have an error. it seems this problem about the coxphfitter().does any one here that solve this problem. I think the lifelines library can not compute coefficients with ML method .So here I copy errors and sample code .I should to say I write the code just for example and inputs not reall.

**code**

```
df_l=df[['Observed','HighLTV','Liquidation']]
    df_c=df[['Observed','HighLTV','Cure']]
    cph_l=CoxPHFitter()
    cph_c=CoxPHFitter()
    cph_l.fit(df_l,'Observed',event_col='Liquidation')
    cph_c.fit(df_c,'Observed',event_col='Cure')
    beta_cure=float('{:.3f}'.format((cph_c.params_[0])))
    beta_liquidation=float('{:.3f}'.format((cph_l.params_[0])))
```

**error**

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifelines\fitters\coxph_fitter.py in _newton_rhapson_for_efron_model(self, X, T, E, weights, entries, initial_point, step_size, precision, show_progress, max_steps)
   1497             try:
-> 1498                 inv_h_dot_g_T = spsolve(-h, g, assume_a="pos", check_finite=False)
   1499             except (ValueError, LinAlgError) as e:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py in solve(a, b, sym_pos, lower, overwrite_a, overwrite_b, debug, check_finite, assume_a, transposed)
    247                            overwrite_b=overwrite_b)
--> 248         _solve_check(n, info)
    249         rcond, info = pocon(lu, anorm)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py in _solve_check(n, info, lamch, rcond)
     28     elif 0 < info:
---> 29         raise LinAlgError('Matrix is singular.')
     30 

LinAlgError: Matrix is singular.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConvergenceError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-7cb92b8db8fe> in <module>
      8     k.append(list(map(lambda x: random.choice(o),range(10))))
      9     s=pd.DataFrame(k[i],columns=df.columns)
---> 10     c.append(CCR(s))

<ipython-input-144-da506c585def> in CCR(data)
     30     cph_c=CoxPHFitter()
     31     cph_l.fit(df_l,'Observed',event_col='Liquidation')
---> 32     cph_c.fit(df_c,'Observed',event_col='Cure')
     33     beta_cure=float('{:.3f}'.format((cph_c.params_[0])))
     34     beta_liquidation=float('{:.3f}'.format((cph_l.params_[0])))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifelines\utils\__init__.py in f(model, *args, **kwargs)
     52         def f(model, *args, **kwargs):
     53             cls.set_censoring_type(model, cls.RIGHT)
---> 54             return function(model, *args, **kwargs)
     55 
     56         return f

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifelines\fitters\coxph_fitter.py in fit(self, df, duration_col, event_col, show_progress, initial_point, strata, step_size, weights_col, cluster_col, robust, batch_mode, timeline, formula, entry_col)
    274         """
    275         self.strata = utils.coalesce(strata, self.strata)
--> 276         self._model = self._fit_model(
    277             df,
    278             duration_col,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifelines\fitters\coxph_fitter.py in _fit_model(self, *args, **kwargs)
    595     def _fit_model(self, *args, **kwargs):
    596         if self.baseline_estimation_method == "breslow":
--> 597             return self._fit_model_breslow(*args, **kwargs)
    598         elif self.baseline_estimation_method == "spline":
    599             return self._fit_model_spline(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifelines\fitters\coxph_fitter.py in _fit_model_breslow(self, *args, **kwargs)
    608         )
    609         if utils.CensoringType.is_right_censoring(self):
--> 610             model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
    611             return model
    612         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifelines\utils\__init__.py in f(model, *args, **kwargs)
     52         def f(model, *args, **kwargs):
     53             cls.set_censoring_type(model, cls.RIGHT)
---> 54             return function(model, *args, **kwargs)
     55 
     56         return f

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifelines\fitters\coxph_fitter.py in fit(self, df, duration_col, event_col, show_progress, initial_point, strata, step_size, weights_col, cluster_col, robust, batch_mode, timeline, formula, entry_col)
   1225         )
   1226 
-> 1227         params_, ll_, variance_matrix_, baseline_hazard_, baseline_cumulative_hazard_, model = self._fit_model(
   1228             X_norm,
   1229             T,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifelines\fitters\coxph_fitter.py in _fit_model(self, X, T, E, weights, entries, initial_point, step_size, show_progress)
   1353         show_progress: bool = True,
   1354     ):
-> 1355         beta_, ll_, hessian_ = self._newton_rhapson_for_efron_model(
   1356             X, T, E, weights, entries, initial_point=initial_point, step_size=step_size, show_progress=show_progress
   1357         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifelines\fitters\coxph_fitter.py in _newton_rhapson_for_efron_model(self, X, T, E, weights, entries, initial_point, step_size, precision, show_progress, max_steps)
   1505                     )
   1506                 elif isinstance(e, LinAlgError):
-> 1507                     raise exceptions.ConvergenceError(
   1508                         """Convergence halted due to matrix inversion problems. Suspicion is high collinearity. {0}""".format(
   1509                             CONVERGENCE_DOCS

ConvergenceError: Convergence halted due to matrix inversion problems. Suspicion is high collinearity. Please see the following tips in the lifelines documentation: https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html#problems-with-convergence-in-the-cox-proportional-hazard-modelMatrix is singular.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given clearly states the problem:

> ConvergenceError: Convergence halted due to matrix inversion problems.
> Suspicion is high collinearity. Please see the following tips in the
> lifelines documentation:
> https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html#problems-with-convergence-in-the-cox-proportional-hazard-modelMatrix
> is singular.

Without the real data I can't give any further advice. But the lifelines documentation gives a lot of advice on this issue:

> Convergence halted due to matrix inversion problems: This means that
> there is high collinearity in your dataset. That is, a column is equal
> to the linear combination of 1 or more other columns. A common cause
> of this error is dummying categorical variables but not dropping a
> column, or some hierarchical structure in your dataset. Try to find
> the relationship by: adding a penalizer to the model, ex:
> CoxPHFitter(penalizer=0.1).fit(…) until the model converges. In the
> print_summary(), the coefficients that have high collinearity will
> have large (absolute) magnitude in the coefs column. using the
> variance inflation factor (VIF) to find redundant variables. looking
> at the correlation matrix of your dataset, or

This is very likely not an error caused by lifelines instead it is your data or how you apply the model on your data.

Comment: I solved my problem, but I was wondering, how can I calculate coefficients without using the lifelines package? I saw somewhere that they had calculated with the statsmodels package. Is that possible give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the package you are using here, but I notice `assume_a="pos"` is included in the `spsolve` call, hinting to the solver that the matrix is positive definite. In my own work, interacting with the scipy solvers directly, I've noticed that the matrix soundness checks can be stricter when this option is set, and that omitting this option (implicitly setting `assume_a="gen"`) *may* yield a usable solution, even for positive definite matrices with undesirably high collinearity.

Comment: This is interesting, @nochmal, I'll investigate this idea for lifelines, too